# Image in sharepoint 2013 rich-text control generate js error

Tags: javascript, richhtmlfield

I have sharepoint 2013 rich text control in page-layout.After adding image in rich-text control ,I am not able to get any html object using js.I am using  below line to alert div object.

> alert($('#linkMainImgDiv'));

It alerts null after adding image in rich-text control.But it works (alert [object]) if I add any content exclude image.And don't have any other js errors in page.Don't know why this control is behaving like this and this behavior is same in all the browsers.

Comment: This is working correctly guys you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.Use jQuery instead $.Don't know why it is behaving like this.So now I have assign jQuery to $  and it works.

> $ = jQuery; alert($('#linkMainImgDiv').html())

Comment: That's because somebody very smart at Microsoft decided it'd be a good idea to assign some sharepoint internal value to a $ variable, thus breaking jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  alert($('#linkMainImgDiv').html())
```

First check in you page source that even this id exist or not. If exist then try it in your debugger tool of browser.

> Can you share your markup or any screenshot with div.

Comment: But $('#linkMainImgDiv') is null.

Comment: Yes, It is exist in page source and also try to debug but it shows null.